# Wrong uv in ray tracer

Tags: c++, raytracing

I have a problem with my ray tracer program. The image looks wrong. Here is the output image:

[image: out]

Barycentric coordinates and collision calculation codes are as follows:

```
bool CTriangle::Intersect(Calculus::CRay& ray, CIntersection* isect) const {
// Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm
const Calculus::CPoint3<float>& p1 = v_points[0];
const Calculus::CPoint3<float>& p2 = v_points[1];
const Calculus::CPoint3<float>& p3 = v_points[2];

Calculus::CVector3<float> e1 = p2 - p1;
Calculus::CVector3<float> e2 = p3 - p1;
Calculus::CVector3<float> s1 = Calculus::Math::Cross(ray.direction, e2);
float determinant = Calculus::Math::Dot(s1, e1);

if (determinant == 0.0f)
    return false;

float inv_determinant = 1.0f / determinant;

Calculus::CVector3<float> s = ray.origin - p1;
float b1 = Calculus::Math::Dot(s, s1) * inv_determinant;
if (b1 < 0.0f || b1 > 1.0f)
    return false;

Calculus::CVector3<float> s2 = Calculus::Math::Cross(s, e1);
float b2 = Calculus::Math::Dot(ray.direction, s2) * inv_determinant;
if (b2 < 0.0f || b1 + b2 > 1.0f)
    return false;

float b0 = 1 - b1 - b2;

float thit = Calculus::Math::Dot(e2, s2) * inv_determinant;
if (thit < ray.mint || thit > ray.maxt)
    return false;

isect->p = ray(thit);
isect->n = Calculus::Math::Normalize(Calculus::CVector3<float> 
(v_normals[0].x, v_normals[0].y, v_normals[0].z) * b0 +
    Calculus::CVector3<float>(v_normals[1].x, v_normals[1].y, 
v_normals[1].z) * b1 +
    Calculus::CVector3<float>(v_normals[2].x, v_normals[2].y, 
v_normals[2].z) * b2);
isect->uv = v_uvs[0] * b0 + v_uvs[1] * b1 + v_uvs[2] * b2;
isect->tHit = thit;
isect->ray_epsilon = 1e-5f * thit;

return true;
}
```

Texture i used int the ray trace program:(file type: bmp)

[image: Texture1]

my obj file is as follows. The background shape consists of two triangles. Texture projection is applied only to the background shape:

```
v  -24.1456 -11.1684 -26.2413
v  24.1455 -11.1684 -26.2413
v  -24.1456 37.1227 -26.2413
v  24.1455 37.1227 -26.2413
# 4 vertices

vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
# 6 vertex normals

vt 0.9995 0.0005 0.0000
vt 0.0005 0.0005 0.0000
vt 0.9995 0.9995 0.0000
vt 0.0005 0.9995 0.0000
# 4 texture coords

o back
g back
usemtl default
s 1
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 4/4/3 
f 4/4/4 3/3/5 1/1/6 
# 2 faces
```

Here is the interpolated uv draw call.

[image]

Here is indexing algorithm, i'm starting from zero:

```
...
Calculus::CPoint3<unsigned short> p, t, n;
sscanf_s(token, "%hu/%hu/%hu %hu/%hu/%hu %hu/%hu/%hu",
    &p.x, &t.x, &n.x, &p.y, &t.y, &n.y, &p.z, &t.z, &n.z);
pi.push_back(p);
ti.push_back(t);
ni.push_back(n);
…

index = ti[i].x - 1;
temp_t[0] = vt[index]; // first uv
index = ti[i].y - 1;
temp_t[1] = vt[index]; // second uv
index = ti[i].z - 1;
temp_t[2] = vt[index]; // third uv
```

I wonder where I'm making a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: try drawing your UVs as a color, like rgb (u,v,0), instead of the texture, and see what happens.

Comment: it interpolates linearly, but one of triangle green-yellow and other interpolated as red-black color. Thank you.

Comment: If one of the triangles is green/yellow, with no 100% red and no 100% green, then your uv calculation is wrong. Draw your bary coords and see what those look like. This is graphics debugging or, as I like to call it: guessing. (Also, I' assume you noticed that your texture is flipped in the screenshot you posted.)

Comment: Take screenshots of the UV and bary rendering and update your question with it.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: You're loading the texture from a `bmp`, right? In `bmp` format, pixels are stored starting from the bottom-left corner, so you either have to account for that in your uv assignment, or, better, save the texture in a sane format.  Also, your `uv`plot shows (0,0) uv at the bottom-right of the quad, with `u` increasing to the left and `v` increasing upward, putting `(1,1)` at the top-left vertex. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Normally, I would expectuv  (0,0) to be the upper-left, and (1,1) to be the lower-right. Based on your uv image, and that the image is a BMP, your output is correct. How are you loading / decoding the image? (If the height in the image header is negative, then they are stored top-to-bottom)

Comment: @3Dave:Yes I'm loading texture from BMP file and I will try the other formats.  I don't know this is what I want. Here is how I getting the image: `rgb = pixels[3 * (x * width + y)+(0)(1)(2)]/255.0f;`

Comment: Should by `y*width+x`, not `x*width+y`. And, you may need to flip vertically, so try `((height-y-1)*width)+x`. Depending on how you're loading the image, the vertical flip (bmp order) may already be taken care of. A lot of libraries do that for you.

Comment: @3Dave: I will try this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isect->uv = v_uvs[0] * b1 + v_uvs[1] * b2;
```

This is not the correct parametric interpolation of vertex attributes:

- The parameters `b1, b2` are being applied to the wrong vertices
- You are not taking the third vertex `v_uvs[2]` into account

Correct version:

```
isect->uv = v_uvs[0] * b0 + v_uvs[1] * b1 + v_uvs[2] * b2;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I didn't add the code because w is zero.. I've updated the code and output, but the error still continues.

Comment: @ADesignersEncyclopedia how are you parsing the OBJ files; it might be an indexing problem. What are the values of the `v_uvs`? And how are you sampling the texture?

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog v_points = '{{x=-24.1455994 y=-11.1683998 z=-26.2413006 }, {x=24.1455002 y=-11.1683998 z=-26.2413006 }, {x=24.1455002 y=37.1226997 z=-26.2413006 }} v_uvs = {{x=1.00000000 y=0.000000000 }, {x=0.000000000 y=0.000000000 }}' I'm getting pixel from bmp file as: r = pixels[3 * (x * width + y) and added +1 to other g b value.

Comment: Because w = 0.0 so didn't want to add.

Comment: Because i didn't use z (depth) texture. I guess only u and v are enough.

Comment: @ADesignersEncyclopedia you still don't understand - I meant there are only two UV **pairs** (2x XY) in the `v_uvs` array, instead of 3. i.e. you have `{{x, y}, {x, y}}` but it should be `{{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}}`; you need one `{x, y}` pair per vertex.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I did the correction, it's better now. But it turned 90 degrees.

Comment: @ADesignersEncyclopedia okay that's a good start, because now the entire texture is visible. The next step would be to either 1) check your camera setup (is the up direction correct?), or 2) swap the texture coordinates in your OBJ file to adjust the orientation of the texture.